# Systemd timer for the first business day of every month

Tags: scheduler, systemd

Just wondering if there is a way to schedule a timer for the first business day of every month?
Basically the first day of every month which is not a weekend.
I am trying to avoid creating a wrapper script if possible

Answer (score 3):

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-1..3 00:00:00
```

This executes the service

1. only if it is a business day
2. only the first 3 days of the month

The intersection of these directives leads to the first business day (Monday to Friday) of every month.

Examples:

- Day 1 is Saturday, day 2 is Sunday, day 3 is Monday. Script runs the 3rd
- Day 1 is Sunday, day 2 is Monday. Script runs the 2nd
- Day 1 is Thursday. Script runs the 1st

Source: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Realtime_timer)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem right... As it should be able to run on any working day - not just Monday. If ithe 1st of a month falls on a working day - it runs. If the 1st of a month falls on a weekend, it should run on Monday

Comment: @r.sendecky ops, what about now?

Comment: Yep, that's what I came up with as well. It still doesn't do what I need. If the 1st falls on Monday, then it will execute 3 times: 1st, 2nd and 3d. I need it to execute just once. On the first working day of the month only! I was looking for a way to logically OR the sequence of days. I want it like this: ( 1 || 2 || 3 ). If it executes on the 1st, then the rest of the days should be skipped. I don't think it is possible as I went through all the systemd docs I could find. Would be nice if the range 1..3 was a logical AND, and the  commas were 1,2,3 a logical OR.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-01
OnCalendar=Mon *-*-02..03
```

There are two `OnCalendar` conditions needed. This can be done in one timer.

- `Mon..Fri *-*-01` will activate if the first day of the month is a business day
- `Mon *-*-02..03` will activate if the second or third day of the month is a Monday. This happens if the first was a Sunday, or if the first was a Saturday and the second was a Sunday. There is no overlap.

To verify this you can use:

```
systemd-analyze calendar 'Mon..Fri *-*-01' 'Mon *-*-02..03' --iterations 10
```

I find it easier to verify if you filter and sort only the iterations by appending `|grep Iteration |sort -k4`, but this will cut off the first iteration.

You can do a very similar thing but in reverse with the **last business day of the month**:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*~01
OnCalendar=Fri *-*~02..03
```

With [systemd v233](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v233/NEWS#L174) you can specify a day relative to the end of the month. Instead of using `-` before the day you use `~`.

- `Mon..Fri *-*~01` triggers if the last day of the month is a business day
- `Fri *-*~02..03` triggers if the second to last or third to last day of the month was a Friday. This happens if the weekend is on the last day of the month.

Again, you can verify this using:

```
systemd-analyze calendar 'Mon..Fri *-*~01' 'Fri *-*~02..03' --iterations 10
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the use of systemd-analyze